# Add several attributes and namespace prefix after flattened JSON data

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

After having flattened parsed JSON data, I would like to add several attributes and namespace prefix, based on previous JSON array key grouping. This question is similar to:
[Add attributes to matched parsed json-to-xml map prior to flatten data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67554051)

...with the difference that in this case the attributes are attempted to be added after the flattening and without tunneling.
Reason of trying to achieve this is to control adding attributes based on previous JSON file array grouping.

I cannot use the method of processing the JSON directly using "parse-json", because this is just a minimal JSON code example. The real data is larger and comes from user which means some data is unknown (thus cannot be hardcoded).

My code is visible here:
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVAkJ3X/1

Below you find extractions of code:

**data.json**

```
<data>

{
  "ix_hidden": [
    {
    "CompanyName": "Link Inc",
    "OrganisationNumber": "123"
    }
  ],

  "other": [
    {
      "SomethingElse": "Juice"
    }
  ]

}

</data>
```

**XSL:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xbrli="http://www.example.com/1"
  xmlns:ix="http://www.example.com/2"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.example.com/3"
  >

  <xsl:output method="xml"/>

<!-- Parse JSON to XML -->

  <xsl:template match="data">
  <xbrli:xbrl>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(.)/*"/>
  </xbrli:xbrl>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Flatten data, exlude high-level key names-->

<xsl:template match="*[@key and not(*)]">
  <xsl:element name="{@key}">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsl:element>

<!-- Add attributes and NS prefix to [ix_hidden] -->

  <xsl:for-each select="*[@key = 'ix_hidden']/*">
    <xsl:attribute name="attributeOne">1</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="attributeTwo">2</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="attributeThree">3</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="attributeFour">4</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="attributeFive">5</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:for-each>

  <!-- Add attributes and NS prefix to [other] -->

    <xsl:for-each select="*[@key = 'other']/*">
      <xsl:attribute name="contextRef">balance0</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xbrli:xbrl xmlns:ix="http://www.example.com/2" xmlns:xbrli="http://www.example.com/1">
  <CompanyName>Link Inc</CompanyName>
  <OrganisationNumber>123</OrganisationNumber>
  <SomethingElse>Juice</SomethingElse>
</xbrli:xbrl>
```

**Wanted result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xbrli:xbrl xmlns:ix="http://www.example.com/2" xmlns:xbrli="http://www.example.com/1">
  <ix:CompanyName attributeOne="1" attributeTwo="2" attributeThree="3" attributeFour="4" attributeFive="5">Link Inc</ix:CompanyName>
  <ix:OrganisationNumber attributeOne="1" attributeTwo="2" attributeThree="3" attributeFour="4" attributeFive="5">123</ix:OrganisationNumber>
  <tx:SomethingElse contextRef="balance0">Juice</tx:SomethingElse>
</xbrli:xbrl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following (https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVAkJ3X/2) might help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xbrli="http://www.example.com/1"
  xmlns:ix="http://www.example.com/2"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.example.com/3"
  xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
  exclude-result-prefixes="fn"
  expand-text="yes"
  >
    
  <xsl:attribute-set name="s1">
    <xsl:attribute name="attributeOne">1</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="attributeTwo">2</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="attributeThree">3</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="attributeFour">4</xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="attributeFive">5</xsl:attribute>      
  </xsl:attribute-set>
  
  <xsl:attribute-set name="s2">
    <xsl:attribute name="contextRef">balance0</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:attribute-set>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<!-- Parse JSON to XML -->

  <xsl:template match="data">
      <xbrli:xbrl>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="json-to-xml(.)/*"/>
      </xbrli:xbrl>
  </xsl:template>

<!-- Flatten data, exlude high-level key names-->

<xsl:template match="*[@key and not(*)]">
  <xsl:element name="{@key}">{.}</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Add attributes and NS prefix to [ix_hidden] -->

<xsl:template match="fn:array[@key = 'ix_hidden']//*[@key and not(*)]">
    <xsl:element name="ix:{@key}" namespace="http://www.example.com/2" use-attribute-sets="s1">{.}</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<!-- Add attributes to [other] -->

<xsl:template match="fn:array[@key = 'other']//*[@key and not(*)]">
    <xsl:element name="tx:{@key}" namespace="http://www.example.com/3" use-attribute-sets="s2">{.}</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I will go ahead and accept the answer since the xsltfiddle passed without errors. In my environment, running same code setup I get 3 warnings: Matches both "fn:array[@key = 'ix_hidden']//*[@key and not(*)]" on line 40 of [file]
and "*[fn:exists(...) and fn:empty(...)]" on line 36 of [file]. The other line pairs it complaints about is same errror but lines: 46 and 36.

Comment: @Toolbox, I have left the original, general purpose template in there as it would handle any leaf elements of more complex input where you have additional contents than the two that need special treatment and get their own templates (e.g. `ix_hidden` or `other`). If you have only those two elements you can remove the template `match="*[@key and not(*)]"`. If you want to get rid of the warning only then put e.g. `priority="5"` on the  specialized templates.

Comment: The warning can also be avoided by declaring `<xsl:mode warning-on-multiple-match="false" on-multiple-match="use-last"/>` to establish that the last matching template wins and that no warning is raised.